Resources for learning Mandarin Chinese: should we have it at all?
This topic is a sort of survey to see if the community likes the thought of having a single CW question to keep all of the resources in one place.
I must say that regardless of the votes, questions about resources won't be allowed in the future, unless they are really well-written, but I doubt that. 

Vote this question up, if you want the CW to exist.
Vote this question down, if you think it shouldn't exist.

If you have something to say, other than a vote, feel free to post an answer. I'll keep this question up for a week and see what comes out. :)
Note: The votes on this questions will be taken as conclusive. Even one exceeding upvote/downvote will determine if the answer is yes or no. So it's the community that will decide. 
Since I can't vote on my own post, it can't be seen but I'll consider it when the week ends. :)

EDIT: According to the votes shown here, the CW has been approved by the community:




Care to [edit] the post to link to the CW question?  Suggested edits are not allowed on meta.

I think this is a great idea! A central place for resources will definitely be useful.
Though I am not 100% certain that the categories will work though, since many resources (in particular online ones) will span beginner, intermediate and advanced - for example: http://www.trainchinese.com/
Also, would it be a good idea for a new category for "tools"? That is, resources that will help understanding Chinese in general, but without a specific 'structure/course', for example:

http://www.mdbg.net/chindict/chindict.php - online dictionary
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kkmlkkjojmombglmlpbpapmhcaljjkde - extension for chrome that translates from Chinese -> English when you hover over characters
https://market.android.com/details?id=com.embermitre.hanping.app - Chinese/English dictionary for Android


I added the dictionaries section, feel free to add them. Use the link button, so they come out neat.
